# Caret genetic algorithm features selection with LDA

Tags: genetic-algorithm, lda, caret

I am trying to run a genetic algorithm in R to do a feature selection over a dataset. I would like to employ LDA as function to classify the data. However I cannot find any function in `caret` to perform this. Any ideas?